# CreateJS error: Cannot assign to read only property 'tweenjs_count' of qContainer

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am trying to use an array of elements in a function and I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tweenjs_count' of qContainer.

```
function handleKeyDown(e)
{   
if (!e) {
  var e = window.event;
 }
     if (e.keyCode=='1'.charCodeAt(0)) {

        var imagearray = ["qContainer", "milkContainer"];
        imagearray.forEach(function(element) {
        jumpElemets(element );
     });
     jumpElemets(imagearray );
     }

     }
     function jumpElemets(element) {
     createjs.Tween.get(element, {loop: false})
        .to({alpha: 0 ,y: element.y +10}, 200, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
        .to({alpha: 1, y: element.y -10}, 200, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
        .to({alpha: 0,y: element.y }, 100, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
        .to({alpha: 1}, 100, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `jumpElemets()` with each element, and then again with the whole array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `jumpElemets(imagearray );`. This is because the createJS Tween takes in an element and you are sending it an array of elements.

Also, there seems no use for the line. I would take the line out completely

```
function handleKeyDown(e)
{   
   if (!e) {
     var e = window.event;
   }
   if (e.keyCode=='1'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        var imagearray = [qContainer, milkContainer];
        imagearray.forEach(function(element) {
           jumpElemets(element );
        });
   }
}

 function jumpElemets(element) {
 createjs.Tween.get(element, {loop: false})
    .to({alpha: 0 ,y: element.y +10}, 200, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
    .to({alpha: 1, y: element.y -10}, 200, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
    .to({alpha: 0,y: element.y }, 100, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
    .to({alpha: 1}, 100, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));

 }
```

From CreateJS docs

> target Object
>   The target object that will have its properties tweened.

is not an array

http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html

Comment: I tried to remove jumpElemets(imagearray ); but i have the same error

Comment: i tried also this :            if (e.keyCode=='3'.charCodeAt(0)) {
  
  var imagearray = ["qContainer", "milkContainer"];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  jumpElemets(imagearray[i]);
   
  }
  }   and always the same error

Comment: Um. You cannot run the Tween method on strings either. Try `imagearray=[qContainer,milkcontainer]`